# How to erase the background of a window?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

### **Please another way than using a layered window.**

Setting **`SetLayeredWindowAttributes`** caused some issues in my GUI, for example, some controls inherit the background color as they contains transparency, same with pictures containing transparency, also there are a lot of other controls loaded on it which makes it hard to work with a layered window.

My goal is to create a GUI with rounded borders, for that, I will load a picture to behave as the background.

**`SetWindowRgn`** would not help, as it doesn't produce good edges borders because the pictures are being drawn with rounded corners and anti-aliasing.

Result using`SetLayeredWindowAttributes` and `SetWindowRgn`:

[image]

I have tried to set `WM_ERASEBKGND` to `true` and inside of `WM_PAINT` use `BitBlt` with the rasters `SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT` painting an empty bitmap into the window DC, but the window still contains a background.

Also tried to just paint the image above, but the empty area is painted with the default background color.
The image used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oizCn.png

I have created a similar ask-for-help topic in the [Microsoft forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/705880/how-to-create-a-window-without-background-or-39era.html#answer-705830), the code below was adapted from an answer given by the user `Castorix`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Gdiplus 
#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus.lib" ) 
#pragma comment( lib, "Msimg32.lib" ) 

#include <gdiplus.h> 
#include <wingdi.h>

//#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
 name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
 processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")



HINSTANCE hInst;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int nWidth = 601, nHeight = 301;
#define IDC_BUTTON 11

HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;



int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance;
    WNDCLASSEX wcex =
    {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW, WndProc, 0, 0, hInst, LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION),
        LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1), NULL, TEXT("WindowClass"), NULL,
    };
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Cannot register class !"), TEXT("Error"), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    int nX = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - nWidth) / 2, nY = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - nHeight) / 2;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wcex.lpszClassName, TEXT("Test"), WS_POPUP, nX, nY, nWidth, nHeight, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
        return MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Cannot create window !"), TEXT("Error"), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        //WndProc(hWnd, 15, 0, 0);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hWndButton = NULL, hWndStatic = NULL;
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hDC;
    BLENDFUNCTION bf{};
    int x = 0, y = 0, dx = 0, dy = 0;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        hWndButton = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Button", L"Click", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHLIKE, 50, 60, 60, 32, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON, hInst, NULL);

        // https://i.stack.imgur.com/oizCn.png

        // Start Gdiplus 
        Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
        ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
        Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);


        // Load the image 
        Gdiplus::Color Color{ 255, 255, 255 };

        hBitmap = NULL;

        Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"C:\\MEGAsync\\pic2.png", false);
        if (bitmap)
        {
            bitmap->GetHBITMAP(Color, &hBitmap);
            delete bitmap;
        }

        //hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"C:\\MEGAsync\\pic.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); 
         return 0;
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDC_BUTTON:
        {
            if (wmEvent == BN_CLICKED)
            {
                Beep(1000, 10);
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return 0;
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        return HTCAPTION;
    case WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        Sleep(200);
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        OutputDebugString(L"WM_PAINT");

        if (hBitmap)
        {
            BITMAP bm;
            GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
            HDC hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
            HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDCMem, hBitmap);

            //SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
            //SetBkMode(hDCMem, TRANSPARENT);

            //TransparentBlt(hDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hDCMem, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, RGB(192, 0, 192));

            bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
            bf.BlendFlags = 0;
            bf.AlphaFormat = 1; // 0 - ignore source alpha, AC_SRC_ALPHA (1) - use source alpha
            bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 10;

            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            dx = nWidth;
            dy = nHeight;
            AlphaBlend(hDC, x, y, dx, dy, hDCMem, x, y, dx, dy, bf);
            auto err = GetLastError();

            //BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hDCMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
            //SelectObject(hDCMem, hBitmapOld);
            DeleteDC(hDCMem);
        }
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Working into the `WM_PAINT` message, I tried to draw the picture into the background using [AlphaBlend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend), but it resulted in the window background being drawn with whatever be underneath it:
[image]

Comment: Use a layered window, LWA_COLORKEY in the SetLayeredWindowAttributes() call to make the background color transparent.

Comment: A layered window can have a transparent background and also have controls. Just make sure the background is using a unique color that the controls don't use.

Comment: Im trying to find another way than using a layered window, isn't possible?

Comment: Do you want to succeed or is it more important not to use a layered window?

Comment: So its not possible to achieve this other than using a layered window? @DavidHeffernan maybe handling the msg of erasebackground or ?

Comment: @Jabu it is *possible* with effort, but WHY don't you want to use a layered window? It is the correct tool for the job. Let the OS do the work for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau because my GUI contains each type of different controls, I don't know how to work with layered windows and controls, and the only thing I need to finish the entire project is to remove/erase the background. If you could give me at least a start to what to search I thank you.

Comment: "*my GUI contains each type of different controls*" - What does that have to do with anything? A layered window can have controls. "*I don't know how to work with layered windows*" - Give the window a unique background color, like Fuschia, and then use [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) to make that color transparent. See [Window Features: Layered Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows).

Comment: @RemyLebeau The border edges inherit a bit of the background color https://i.imgur.com/KB9TSeG.png (I set the background black, and then call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`) I also test with fuchsia, same result.

Comment: @Jabu that is due to the rounded corners being drawn with anti-aliasing, so those pixels are not the pure transparent color. Either don't draw the corners with anti-aliasing, or else use `SetWindowRgn()` instead of `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau `SetWindowRgn` also doesn't produce got edges border, whats the option you said with `it is possible with effort`

Comment: @Jabu "*`SetWindowRgn` also doesn't produce got edges border*" - assuming you meant *good edges*, what do you mean, exactly? Probably the *lack* of anti-aliasing and alpha-blending, right? "*whats the option you said with `it is possible with effort`*" - using regions, or handling `WM_ERASEBKGND`/`WM_PAINT` to omit painting a background, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is exactly what i was trying before creating this post, handle the WM_ERASEBKGND to omit the background, how I'm doing at WM_ERASEBKGND return 1, then in WM_PAINT CreateCompatibleDC, SetBkMode Transparent, BeginPaint BitBlt from Gui dc to the new dc, but the GUI still contain a background

Comment: @Jabu then you need to update your question to show the actual code you have tried (with and without using a layered window) and explain why it is not working for your needs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i have added more information to the topic.

Comment: @Jabu "*My goal is to create a GUI with rounded borders, for that, I will load a picture to behave as the background*" - you didn't say before that you want to use a picture for the window background. In that case, you can use `UpdateLayeredWindow()`. Use that picture to create a pre-multiplied bitmap for both shaping the window and specifying its alpha/transparency on a per-pixel basis. So, you can have nice rounded anti-aliased edges, while avoiding transparency inside the window where controls will reside. Also, when using `UpdateLayeredWindow()`, you don't need to handle `WM_PAINT` anymore

Comment: @RemyLebeau but my window is not a layered window.

Comment: @Jabu I know, but it *should be*, since that is the best solution for this task. Prior to Windows 2000, regions were the only solution for making oddly shaped UIs, but that changed when Layered Windows were introduced for this very task, and they do so much more efficiently. And the fact that you want to use a picture is even more so, since you can define the window in terms of that picture, that is what `UpdateLayeredWindow()` is specifically meant for.

Answer (score 2):

A layered window with the LWA_COLORKEY attribute is problematic if you want (Windows standard) child controls because there is no perfect color to pick as the transparent color.

However, layered windows have another mode; [UpdateLayeredWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow). This function is perfect if you have an image (with alpha transparency) you want to use as the background. Just make sure the bitmap is pre-multiplied 32-bit ARGB before selecting it into the DC.

If for some crazy reason you can't use layered windows, the older option is [SetWindowRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn).

The newer option is [DirectComposition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directcomp/directcomposition-portal) but I'm not sure if you are forced to set the layered style on the window.

Comment: "*there is no perfect color to pick as the transparent color*" - true, but there are colors that are highly unlikely to be used for anything else, like Fuschia, which are ideally/commonly used for handling transparency.